# How do I play this chord on the accordion

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, accordion

[image]

I am new to the accordion and was playing The god father waltz and I came across these note and I have no idea how to play it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a chord, I'm assuming that the chord is on the bass clef. (If not, could your post a picture with more context?)

The accordion convention is that bass notes represent major chords. Thus, as the note is a D, it represents some type of D chord on the bass side. The small "m" indicates a minor chord. So, you play the D-minor chord.

Additional accordion information: The usual Stradella layout has 6 bass buttons for each note; the notes are arranged by the circle of fifths. The second button from the bottom (at least I think it's the bottom) is the root note. The 3 note at the bottom is a major third above that root (allows for a walking bass and the like); the next row are 3-note major chords, then 3-note minor chords, then 3-note dominant seventh (fifth missing which allows for Augmented Sixths), then 3-note diminished seventh missing the fifth.
https://accordionchords.com/stradella-bass-layouts/120-bass-accordion-chart/

Comment: No. The bass is independent. Usually, the bass lines and chords have separate reeds. You can hold them to  make a richer sound.